# TypeError: Web3 is not a constructor when trying to use node.js with truffle-contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, nodejs, truffle-contract

I'm trying to use node.js with my smart contract for my app. As I've tried to convert from using the default `app.js` set-up to `index.js` set-up I've ran into this weird issue I can't fix.

It throws the error when trying to instantiate my .json file with truffle-contract.

```
App.contracts.Flip = TruffleContract(FlipArtifact); //at this line it goes to truffle-contract.js and throws this error: 

var BigNumber = (new Web3()).toBigNumber(0).constructor;

TypeError: Web3 is not a constructor
```

I had the exact same thing but in my app.js where truffle puts it automatically and it was working fine.

Could someone please explain the difference between using truffle-contract in my app.js/client-side and my index.js/server-side. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running in a browser with MetaMask, then `Web3` is injected as a side effect of this (although try not to rely on this behaviour). In server-side code, you must import web3 yourself, by putting something like:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
```

near the start of your code. You may also have to `npm install web3` or `yarn install web3`, and if you're using BigNumber (which they no longer bundle with Web3 1.0) then you probably want to specify `npm install web3@^0.20.6` or `yarn add web3@^0.20.6`.

Comment: Hey @James_pic , I'm currently doing 

    var Web3 = require('web3') 

and that is working fine because without it said "Web3 not a ...". I will try to npm install web3@0.20.6 and see if that works!

Comment: FYI for later readers: [auto-injection is outdated](https://medium.com/metamask/no-longer-injecting-web3-js-4a899ad6e59e).

Comment: this works for me in node v16, but get "not a constructor" after upgrading to node v18 ... TBH, I've had nothing but problems getting anything in web3 working. No example code, nothing works, no documentation - worst experience ever

Answer (score 20):

I was stuck with the same error while trying to use this in nodejs..

I finally found the [fix](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-bridge/issues/34#issuecomment-1588248619). Apparently, in Web3.js 4.x, we're supposed to import it like this:

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
```

Instead of this

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
```

[Refer Docs](https://docs.web3js.org/guides/web3_upgrade_guide/x/)

Comment: Sheesh, I'm new to all this, but had working scripts as of last May. Crazy how by September those scripts are already dated for any new web3 install and needed this { } fix. Thanks yo. This was the solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Saved me ton of time. With node >= 18 this is only acceptable answer

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error "...Web3 is not a constructor."

The issue was in the order in which I had my following included in the html code:

> ```
> <script src="./js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
> <script src="./js/web3.min.js"></script>
> ```

I just made sure web3.min.js script was called before the truffle-contract, and that solved the issue.

Correct order to include:

> ```
> <script src="./js/web3.min.js"></script>
> <script src="./js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer d5t, for my situation doing what James_pic suggested fixed it.

Comment: 2021 and this is what worked for me. Thanks!